# How can I run (recenter) after dired reloads current buffer?

Tags: dired

I don't find any hook related to dired reloading. I tried `after-revert-hook` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `after-revert-hook` but it doesn't work.

The hooks `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook` are guaranteed to be run only by the default `revert-buffer-function`. See [`(elisp) Reverting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reverting.html).

> I don't find any hook related to dired reloading.

Dired sets the function `dired-revert` as its `revert-buffer-function`. Like other Dired functions which read in directories, `dired-revert` runs the hook `dired-after-readin-hook`:

```
dired-after-readin-hook is a variable defined in ‘dired.el’.
Its value is (dired-omit-expunge)
Original value was nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Hook run after each time a file or directory is read by Dired.
After each listing of a file or directory, this hook is run
with the buffer narrowed to the listing.

You can customize this variable.
```

Nevertheless, this hook is not suitable for running `recenter` as it is run in a [narrowed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) buffer.

> How can I run `(recenter)` after dired reloads current buffer?

One solution is to advise `dired-revert`:

```el
(define-advice dired-revert (:after (&rest _) my-recenter)
  "Call `recenter' after `dired-revert'."
  (recenter))
```

or similarly before Emacs 25:

```el
(defun my-recenter (&rest _)
  "Wrap `recenter' while ignoring arguments."
  (recenter))

(advice-add #'dired-revert :after #'my-recenter)
```

Comment: Hmm, after advicing the dired-revert call, I get `apply: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer.` when first opening dired on some directory. The second time works fine though.

Comment: @Amos Can you reproduce it if you start Emacs with the `-Q` flag? Because I can't reproduce it on Emacs 24, 25 or 27 or using any one of `dired`, `dired-other-window` or `dired-other-frame`.